# disable the validation for checkbox on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i had a checkbox with two button(button1, button2) in aspx page . and i am trying to validate this checkbox on button2 click. and the validation should not fire on button1 click.. i know we can use group name concept. but i want it without this concept ...

the check box is

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprove" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-inline" Text="Check here to approve" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" />
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="reqCheckBoxRequired" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic"
        Visible="false" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate">You must select this box to approve and proceed.</asp:CustomValidator>
```

the two buttons

```
        <div class="btn-group">
            <asp:Button ID="btnPreview" type="submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnPreview_Click" OnClientClick="fnIgnoreApprove(true)" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Preview" />
        </div>
        <div class='btn-group'>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" type="submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="fnIgnoreApprove(false)" class="btn btn-success" Text="Save" Visible="false" />
        </div>
```

the script code is

```
<script>

    function CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate(sender, e) {
        if (!document.getElementById("MainContent_reqCheckBoxRequired").disabled) {
            e.IsValid = document.getElementById("<%=chkApprove.ClientID %>").checked;
    }
};
 function fnIgnoreApprove(toDisable) {
        debugger
        var name = document.getElementById("<%= reqCheckBoxRequired.ClientID %>");
        ValidatorEnable(name, toDisable);
    };
```

here reqCheckBoxRequired is the customvalidator id..
i am getting an error that undefined name...

Comment: show html source . not server code .undefined name? then `document.getElementById()` may be undefined .you have to check does id exist

Comment: Just ignore the value of the checkbox on pressing button1?

Comment: @FastSnail 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'enabled' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @htiru first view your site in browser then using console check value of `name` it's undefined .that mean id doesn't exist